# The remainder of $n^{11}$ when divided by $23$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a natural number such that $n$ is not divisible by $23$. Then the remainder when $n^{11}$ is divided by $23$ is $±1(\mod 23)$.

I have solve it by a laborious calculations. Since by division algorithm there exist integers $q$ and $r$ such that $n=23q+r$ where $0<r<23$. Then $n^{11}=(23q+r)^{11}$, then when we divide $(23q+r)^{11}$ by $23$ then we have to notice that the remainder when $r^{11}$ is divided by $23$. It is trivial for $1$ and $22$, but for $r=2$ we have, $2^5≡9~(\mod 23)$ implies $2^{10}≡12(\mod 23)$ implies $2^{11}≡1(\mod 23)$. By proceeding this argument for $r=3,4,5,....,21$ we get our required result. But this method is too vast and laborious. Please help me to solve in any other way easier to the above.

Comment: See "Euler's criterion" in texts on number theory.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown More like $FlT$ instead of Euler's criterion

Comment: $$(n^{11}-1)(n^{11}+1)$$ is divisible by $22+1$ for $(23,n)=1$ by Fermat's Little Theorem

Comment: $$\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)\equiv a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\pmod{p}$$ is Legendre symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem):
$$n^{22} \equiv 1 \pmod {23}$$

Since $23$ is a prime, $\Bbb Z/23\Bbb Z$ is a field, so $x^2-1$ only has two roots over $\Bbb Z/23\Bbb Z$, but we know that those two roots are $\pm1$, so $n^{11} \equiv \pm1 \pmod {23}$ since $n^{11}$ is a solution to $x^2-1=0$.

Informally, the last sentence means "take square root of both sides".